# C++ wchar_t * equals case-insensitive to other wchar_t *

Tags: c++, pointers, equals, case-insensitive, wchar-t

Im trying to check if a wchar_t * equals case-insensitive to another wchar_t *.
Can someone put me in the right way?

There is what I tryed:

```
wchar_t *vectored[80] = { ... };
int i = 0;
int j = 1;
_Towlower(vectored[i], NULL) == _Towlower(vectored[j], NULL);
```

_Tolower() no overload for wchar_t pointer.

Thanks you.

Comment: `_Towlower`? What's a `Tow`?

Comment: @EdS., http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tow

Comment: @chris: ...I think you know what I was getting at :D

Comment: _CRTIMP2_PURE wchar_t __CLRCALL_PURE_OR_CDECL _Towlower(wchar_t, const _Ctypevec *);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you're not using **_towlower** (lowercase **t**)? If so, **_towlower** converts a single character, not a complete string. To compare a complete string, use [**_wcsicmp**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k59z8dwe%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [wcscasecmp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wcscasecmp.html) function if it's available in your implementation.

Comment: Or _wcsicmp if you use Windows.

Comment: wchar.h dosn't contains wcscasecmp in windows.

Comment: @Marcos Eusebi In Windows you can use _wcsicmp